# How to include external page to wordpress page?

Tags: php

I have one external page (`google_map.php`) which contain code to display google map information based on the selection criteria.

And in the wordpress page I want to display the google map which is coded in `google_map.php`.

I want to ask that how can I add `google_map.php` page in my wordpress page?

Or other option,

Can i directly add my `google_map.php` page code to the wordpress page?
I don't want to use any plugin to support php code in the wordpress page like Exec-PHP plugin.

Which is the better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is actually very simple. just

- add the following text in at begining of google_map.php page
- upload this page to your theme folder.
- go to dashboard to create a page, when create a page chose page telmplate: google map.

that is it, you can read more [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates)

```
<?php
/*
 Template Name: google map
*/
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

IMO the best option for what you want to do would be to use the [MapPress plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/mappress-google-maps-for-wordpress/) - the free version works really well and will allow you to embed a customizable google map into any post or page quickly and easily through your admin page editor.

Otherwise you could create a page template and use a php include to call the google_map.php page wherever you want it displayed within your page/post.